# Observer para actualizar una tabla al borrar un registro de otra

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Necesito que al momento de eliminar una Solicitud el Ejemplar quede de nuevo en estado disponible, hice una tarea programada que se ejecuta a diario y se encarga de eliminar las solicitudes pero ahora necesito que ademas pueda actualizar el estado de la otra tabla.

```
public function handle()
    {
        DB::table('solicitudes')
        ->where(DB::raw('current_date()'), '>', DB::raw('fecha_solicitud + (select valor from parametros where id=3)'))
        ->whereNotIn('id', DB::table('seguimientos')->where('estado_ejemplare_id', '<>', 2)->pluck('solicitude_id'))
        ->delete();
    }
```

Aunque no tengo del todo claro la diferencia entre los eventos y los observers creo que el mas adecuado para esta situacion seria el observer, dado que estoy manipulando unicamente el modelo y no necesito hacer nada que manipular la BD.

En mi observer tengo esto al momento de eliminar una solicitud

```
public function deleted(Solicitude $solicitude)
    {
        DB::table('ejemplares')->update(['estado_ejemplare_id' => 1])->where('id', $solicitude->ejemplare_id);
    }
```

Tambien he probado con eloquent.

```
 public function deleted(Solicitude $solicitude)
    {
        Ejemplare::where('id', $solicitude->ejemplare_id)->update(['estado_ejemplare_id' => 1]);
    }
```

En AppServiceProvider tengo lo siguiente

```
public function boot()
    {
        Solicitude::observe(SolicitudeObserver::class);
    }
```

Pero solamente me esta funcionando la tarea programada.
Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Dado que en la tarea programada estaba usando el metodo delete de query builder este no hacia que mi Observer captara esa instruccion y no invocaba al metodo deleted.

Así quedo mi tarea programada.

```
$solicitudes =  DB::table('solicitudes')
        ->where(DB::raw('current_date()'), '>', DB::raw('fecha_solicitud + (select valor from parametros where id=3)'))
        ->whereNotIn('id', DB::table('seguimientos')->where('estado_ejemplare_id', '<>', 2)->pluck('solicitude_id'))
        ->pluck('id');

        Solicitude::destroy($solicitudes);
```

Con esto evite cambiar mi codigo a sintaxis eloquent puro, entonces con pluck solo traje un array con los id que necesita borrar y luego la eliminacion la realice con el modelo y el metodo destroy de eloquent.

Y mi observer quedo de la siguiente manera (no tuvo cambios con respecto a la pregunta)

```
public function deleted(Solicitude $solicitude)
    {
        DB::table('ejemplares')->where('id', $solicitude->ejemplare_id)->update(['estado_ejemplare_id' => 1]);
    }
```

De esta forma cada dia (como esta programada mi tarea para ser ejecutada) elimina las solicitudes que su fecha de reclamo es mayor a la fecha actual, al momento de eliminar los registros el observer se encarga de actualizar los ejemplares de nuevo a su estado disponible.